# How do I disable the theorem counter for \autoref when using an extended theorem name?

Tags: hyperref, theorems, counters

I’m writing a paper, and I need to quote a theorem by a mathematician whom we’ll call *Genius*. This theorem already goes by a well-known name, say *Genius’ Special Theorem*. I’d like to cite this theorem a number of times in my paper, but I have trouble doing so without a theorem counter popping up everywhere. Here is my working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Genius}{Genius' Special Theorem}

\newcommand{\Thmautorefname}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\Geniusautorefname}{Genius' theorem}

% ----------

\begin{document}

Let us begin with the following theorem.

\begin{Thm}
Blah, blah, blah.
\end{Thm}

Now, we have the following theorem discovered by Genius.

\begin{Genius} \label{Genius}
Ha, ha, ha.
\end{Genius}

More text here.

According to \autoref{Genius}, we get...

\end{document}
```

When I preview the PDF document, I see

> According to Genius’ theorem 1, we get...

However, what I’d like is

> According to Genius’ theorem, we get...

because that’s the only theorem by Genius I’m ever going to use in the paper. I tried to remedy this by using `\newtheorem*{Genius}{Genius' Special Theorem}`, but then I get

> According to Theorem 1, we get...

Somehow, the asterisk causes `\autoref` to ignore the command `Genius` and causes it to latch on to the command `Thm` instead.

Could anyone kindly resolve this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want Genius' theorem numbered?

Comment: @egreg: No, not at all. When I introduce Genius’ theorem for the first time in the paper, I’d like it to be called *Genius’ Special Theorem*, and in all subsequent references to the theorem, I’d like to use *Genius’ theorem*. The thing is, I could have typed this manually, but each time I refer to Genius’ theorem, I’d like to have a link that takes the reader back to the original statement, which is supposed to be the function of `\autoref`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `\autoref` is to add the counter's name (or whatever one decides in place of the counter's name) to the number. In your case you just need `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{innerGenius}{Genius' Special Theorem}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Genius}
  {\innerGenius\phantomsection\def\@currentlabel{Genius' Theorem}}
  {\endinnerGenius}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Thmautorefname}{Theorem}

% ----------

\begin{document}

Let us begin with the following theorem.

\begin{Thm}
Blah, blah, blah.
\end{Thm}

Now, we have the following theorem discovered by Genius.

\begin{Genius} \label{Genius}
Ha, ha, ha.
\end{Genius}

More text here.

According to \ref{Genius}, we get...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\newtheorem*` needs `amsthm` that's autoloaded by `amsart`, so with other classes you should add `\usepackage{amsthm}`.

Note that using `\newtheorem*` only wouldn't create the reference for `\label`. So the reference is created in the `Genius` environment by setting `\@currentlabel` manually, adding also `\phantomsection` for creating the anchor.

Comment: Thanks! I actually deleted my comment because I thought it was rather stupid of me to ask it.